# Error ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor Laravel 5.8 Yajra

Tags: laravel, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I get the following error Yajra\Pdo\Oci8\Exceptions\Oci8Exception ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

What I want is to be able to connect to Laravel 5.8.38 to Oracle (remote), and I'm not sure how to do the setup using the **service name**

[Sql Developer Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX4yq.jpg)

```
'connections' => [
    'oracle' => [
        'driver' => 'oracle',
        'host' => '192.168.0.190',
        'port' => '1521',
        'database' => 'BDDESARR',
        'service_name' => '???',
        'username' => 'PAT_GUZ',
        'password' => 'ujUYjjdk',
        'charset' => '',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

Installation of Yajra following the step by step from https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8/tree/5.8

Terminal output

```
PS C:\wamp64\www\desarrollo\php\laravel\miproyect> composer require yajra/laravel-oci8:"5.8.*"
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package jakub-onderka/php-console-color is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-color instead.
Package jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-highlighter instead.
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
```

**File** config/database.php

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'oracle'),
'connections' => [
    'oracle' => [
        'driver' => 'oracle',
        'host' => '192.168.0.190',
        'port' => '1521',
        'database' => 'BDDESARR',
        'service_name' => '???',
        'username' => 'PAT_GUZ',
        'password' => 'ujUYjjdk',
        'charset' => '',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

Additional information, I made the following code and it runs successfully

```
  <?php

$conn = oci_connect('PAT_GUZ', 'ujUYjjdk', '192.168.0.190/BDDESARR');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    var_dump($e);
}

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE');
oci_execute($stid);

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "") . "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

- Laravel  5.8.38
- PHP 7.3.12
- Oracle: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 -
  64bit Production
- Windows 10 64 bit
- Wamp64

Comment: So if the listener doesn't know of the requested SID, then we need to see what the listener _does_ know.  On the database server, as the owner of the oracle installation, execute the command 'lsnrctl status'.  Update your opening post to show the results.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Laravel, Yajra and other things you mentioned, but this:

```
'database' => 'BDDESARR',
'service_name' => '???',
```

looks if not *wrong* then *suspicious*. SQL Developer connection suggests that `Service name = 'bddesarr'`. I don't know what "database" is supposed to be. SID, perhaps, as Oracle complains that SID isn't right.

Answer (score 1):

Try by setting the "DB_SERVICE_NAME" variable in ".env" file.
It worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

- Laravel v10,
- yajra/laravel-oci8 v10
- php v8.2
- oracle 19c

Here the issue was because the TNS env variable was not set. After updating the `.env` and `config/database.php` like bellow it worked:

```
# file: .env
DB_CONNECTION=oracle
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=1521
DB_SERVICE_NAME=orcl
DB_DATABASE=DEVDB
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=secret
DB_SCHEMA=MYAPP
DB_TNS=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DEVDB)))
```

```php
// file: config/database.php

// Other database configs here...

/*
* Oracle Database connection config
*/
'oracle' => [
    'driver' => 'oracle',
    'tns' => env('DB_TNS', ''),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', ''),
    'database' =>  env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'AL32UTF8'),
    'prefix' => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1521'),
    'schema' => env('DB_SCHEMA', ''),
    'server_version' => env('DB_SERVER_VERSION', '19c'),
    'strict' => false,
    'options' => array(
        PDO::ATTR_CASE => env('DB_ATTR_CASE', PDO::CASE_LOWER),
    ),
],
```